# multiple user's accessing same file on tfs

Tags: tfs

Can multiple users work on same file when the file is checked out by other person on tfs.If yes can anyone please let me know the steps to configure tfs.So that both persons can simultaneously access the file.

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? In TFS 2012+ you can use a [Local Workspace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx). Check-out locks when using local workspaces are [redundant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb892960.aspx#check_out_lock_bypass)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible if you configure TFS to allow it. However when the 2nd person checks in the file they may need to get latest and merge the 1st person's changes with their own before they are able to then check-in the file.

To configure TFS follow the MSDN atricle here.

[MSDN article on configuring TFS checkin](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242869(v=vs.100).aspx)

Note: you must be TFS admin to make the config change.

Comment: @Bellis: It worked Thanks alot.